# WebAppBuilder - Print Service/widget problems

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, web-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have an app running on WebAppbuilder. The layers are all on an Enterprise SDE Database. I cannot get the Print widget to function properly. I followed the instructions here to set up my own print service with all the proper specifications. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005q3000000

I also made sure all the services on the map have Web Tier authentication ie "This can be accomplished by configuring the domain account as a member of a user role that has explicit access to each secured service. You can also configure the account as a member of a publisher role that has read access to all services."

I know this is the Print Plus widget, but I was having the exact same issues with the stock Print widget.
[image]

Comment: Ever find a solution?  I am running into a similar problem following the same Esri documentation.

Comment: Nope, no luck yet. We at the moment gave up on printing